# SQL query join or subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, subquery

[![table named teams and Matches[image] ][2]][2]I have 2 tables

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v4nT.png**strong text**

I need data from these 2 tables in such a ways that a new table is formed with the following data

mid, result, date, team1id, team2id from matches table on the basis of tourid=6 and from table of team i need to show the Tname as team1 and Tname as team2.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images. (And I can't read that tiny image text.)

Comment: Please learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a join:

```
select matches.*,t1.Tname as team1,t2.Tname as team2 from matches
join team t1 on t1.Teamid=matches.team1id
join team t2 on t2.Teamid=matches.team2id
where tourid=6
```